# How to map the field name to a custom name in Codigniter's select_sum() function?

Tags: codeigniter

In Codeigniter documentation, there is a function i.e **select_sum()**.

```
$this->db->select_sum('age');
$query = $this->db->get('members'); // Produces: SELECT SUM(age) as age FROM members
```

But I want to change the field name 'age' to 'totalAge'. But if I set "as" after the column then codeigniter is showing some error.

```
$this->db->select_sum('age as totalAge');
$query = $this->db->get('members'); // Produces error wth this: SELECT SUM(age as totalAge) as age FROM members
```

So is it possible to change the field name in **select_sum** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select_sum('age', 'totalAge');
$query = $this->db->get('members');
```

Writes a “SELECT SUM(field)” portion for your query. As with select_max(), You can optionally include a second parameter to rename the resulting field.

see: CI docs [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data)

Have a look at your system/database/DB_query_builder.php at around line 363 and check `public function select_sum($select = '', $alias = '')`, to see how `select_sum()` works.